# How to set a Dynamic path name for FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, javafx, dynamic, path

So I am working on a JavaFX program **(not android)**!

The program works perfectly fine on my computer! 
but when I convert it to .exe and send it to someone else, it doesn't work anymore!

Why? because it depends on my own path directory

```
FileOutputStream down1 = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Asus i7\\Desktop\\untitled1ghthr\\src\\sample\\voices\\"+name.getText()+ex1);
```

This path exist only on my PC, that's why when I give my program to someone else it won't work!
I tried to work with this function but looks like it is only for android

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
```

How can i make a dynamic path so it works on all the PCs ?

Comment: I am using  FileOutputStream to create a new file. I am not trying to load a file. Is there a function that return where is the location of the executed prog? I want the part of (where the user placed his app to be dynamic)

Comment: Ah, right. My mistake. Use a known location such as an application-specific folder in the user home directory (i.e. `System.getProperty("user.home")`). You can also try to use the typical location of the host OS. For instance, on Windows, there's the (local) app-data directory (i.e. `System.getenv("appdata")` or `System.getenv("localappdata")`).

Comment: You can also use the working directory, though you can't guarantee it will be the same directory as the application, nor that it'll be the same location every time.